# react-native "type error: undefined is not a function" for a function bridged from native code

Tags: typescript, react-native, dji-sdk, react-native-bridge

I'm trying to use the react-native-dji-mobile-sdk library (Link to github: https://github.com/Kubessandra/react-native-dji-mobile-sdk). It's a wrapper to bridge native IOS and Android code from the dji mobile sdk to react native.

The specific functions in question are `startTakeoff() and startLanding()` in SDKAircraft.ts.
I've written some basic code to register the app and connect to a DJI drone, and then access the functionality to take off and land. Registration and connection works (from SDKManager.ts). When tested, the remaining methods of SDKAircraft (`getSerialNumber(), getModel(), isConnected()`) work perfectly. But when trying to use startTakeoff() and startLanding() I get the error `"undefined is not a function"` or `"function is undefined".`

My AndroidManifest.xml includes the required

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.dji.sdk.API_KEY"
android:value="Your DJI API Key Here"/>
```

section with a valid API key that registered with the appropriate package name, in the correct place

Here is my App.tsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  useColorScheme,
} from 'react-native';
import { sdkManager, SDKDrone } from 'react-native-dji-mobile-sdk';




function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [drone, setDrone] = useState<SDKDrone | null>(null)
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const register = async () => {
    try {
      await sdkManager.registerApp()
      await sdkManager.startConnectionToProduct()
      const newDrone = await sdkManager.getProduct()
      setDrone(newDrone);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  const takeoff = async () => {
    try {
      if (drone) {
        await drone.startTakeOff()
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  const land = async () => {
    try {
      if (drone) {
        await drone.startLanding()
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Button onPress={register} title='REGISTER' />
      {drone !== null && (<Button onPress={takeoff} title='TAKE OFF' />)}
      {drone !== null && (<Button onPress={land} title='LAND' />)}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

.My build.gradle is configured as such for a reason. My main project has uses react-native-gesture-handler, which for some reason requires the compileSdkVersion to be 33, while the dji wrapper only works if the targetSdkVersion is 31.

Additional Info: I'm building this on a macbook with zulu-11-jdk as my java sdk.

I've tried running this in my main project and with just the simple UI I've created; both give me the same error. I've also tried calling the methods directly in my buttons as such `onPress={drone.startLanding}` and I've tried wrapping my asynchronous methods in synchronous methods as follows and putting those into my button onPress.
This has worked before, over 6 months ago in a separate project which I haven't been able to run successfully within the last month (accessed from a repo)